# IBAction doesn't show up in interface builder

Tags: xcode, cocoa, interface-builder

I've added

```
- (IBAction)printCollection
```

to my class but it doesn't show up in interface builder. I've cleaned the built, restarted interface builder, but it doesn't show up.

The previous (IBAction) are instead all there... I don't get it.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (IBAction)printCollection:(id)sender;
```

Also, make sure you've saved the .h and the xib's File's Owner is correct.